# How to say " I was about to tell you ... " in a native way?

Tags: phrase-request

When there is a topic or subject in my mind and I would like to speak with my friend about this topic and my friend starts to speak about this topic (automatically) before I speak, I would like to tell him that I was about to speak about the same topic. I was about to say the same speech or the same opinion that he said.. What a coincidence!!

Also, When I have a question in my mind and a person tell me the answer through his speech before listening to my question, I would like to tell him that I was about to ask him about what he already answered.

In my native language, When I speak about this coincidence, It shows that I'm interested in that topic and I love to listen to the Peron who speaks.

Is there a native idiom or expression to tell about this coincidence? 
How do you say "I was about to tell you about the same topic that you're saying" in a more native way?  It is OK if the expression is slang.

Comment: The title of your question contains its own answer. You don't need anything else.

Comment: "I was just about to say that!" Tone of voice is everything and enthusiasm is everything.

Comment: I was just going to tell you that.
All the other suggestions have already been posted, so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible sentences that might work for you:

```
I was (just thinking about that), and I agree!
I was just about to say the same thing!
(You read my mind); I agree completely.
(What a coincidences); I was just about to ask you about that!
```

The brackets I added to the sentences above are to highlight English idioms.